# Manually run python file with command it runs fine but when i'm using for process its gives error.(composer require symfony/process)

Tags: python, php, python-3.x, laravel, onnx

"The command "'python3' '/var/www/html/vino_python/rembg-main/app.py'" failed.\n\nExit Code: 1(General error)\n\nWorking directory: /var/www/html/vino_python\n\nOutput:\n================\n\n\nError Output:\n================\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/var/www/html/vino_python/rembg-main/app.py", line 1, in \n    from rembg.bg import remove\n  File "/var/www/html/vino_python/rembg-main/rembg/bg.py", line 7, in \n    from pymatting.alpha.estimate_alpha_cf import estimate_alpha_cf\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymatting/**init**.py", line 2, in \n    from pymatting.util import *\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymatting/util/**init**.py", line 2, in \n    from pymatting.util.kdtree import KDTree, knn\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymatting/util/kdtree.py", line 7, in \n    @njit("i8(i8[:], i8[:], i8[:], i8[:], i8[:], f4[:, :, :], f4[:], f4[:, :], i8[:], i8)", cache=True, nogil=True)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numba/core/decorators.py", line 212, in wrapper\n    disp.enable_caching()\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 863, in enable_caching\n    self._cache = FunctionCache(self.py_func)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numba/core/caching.py", line 613, in **init**\n    self._impl = self._impl_class(py_func)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numba/core/caching.py", line 351, in **init**\n    "for file %r" % (qualname, source_path))\nRuntimeError: cannot cache function '_make_tree': no locator available for file '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymatting/util/kdtree.py'\n",

**I'm Using Python Version 3.7 and also Host Project in AWS Ubuntu 18.04**

Comment: Can you share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem? Why is this tagged with Laravel and PHP, but does not contain any such code?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem occurring in one of my Laravel + Python project where in the Laravel API I executed a python file via Symfony process and solve this type of error by doing the steps:

This is the problem is mainly occurs when you have different version of libraries inside pip install in python dependency.

For solution you must need to follow specific version of pip and python for installing dependecies.

In your case I think you need to delete the **lib** folder from project root if you are using virtual environment.

After that you can again fresh installing via `pip install -r requirements.txt`

I think you will solve your problem by doing this simple steps.